# Is there a right way of animating an armature?

Tags: animation, armature

I can think of these two ways of animating an armature:

- Moving the whole armature object to create the motion path and then animating the bones to match the motion
- Keeping the armature still, but animating bones away from the armature origin to create the motion

I've used both styles in animations, but is there a right option here or are both valid?

The first option does have a downside if you have IKs in your armature where they don't stay in place (relative to world) while you move the whole armature, so making a walking animation can be painful because you have to animate a "counter motion" that for example makes it look like the foot stays on the ground. This is a lot easier in the second option as you can just move the root bone and the IK bones stay still (relative to world) until you move them.

Comment: I would say it all depends on the movement the character is supposed to do, for a large walk, make a walk cycle and move the whole armature, for a small walk, move the bones away from origin?

Comment: There is no absolutely right or wrong way, it all depends on the motion and you already give examples how in different situations different approaches have pros and cons. As long as you are aware there are different mthods, you should always use the one that feels most suitable for what you try to achieve.